# Angular Material Dialog return undefined after close although passed data

Tags: angular, angular-material

I cannot return data after close my Material Dialog. Is there something I am missing?
This is my code

**Parent**

```
openDialog(){
    var myDialogRef= this.dialog.open(SiteAddComponent);    
    
    myDialogRef.componentInstance.dialogRef = myDialogRef;    
    
    myDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(arg => console.log(arg)); // ← arg is 'undefined' here 
  }
```

**Child**

```
dialogRef: any;

close() {
    this.dialogRef.close(1);
}
```

Comment: Hello guys, I've found the rootcause that I've called the closeAll() method in ngOnDestroy() so that Dialog can't return data.

Answer (score 0):

```
  **Parent component html**
    
    <button mat-button (click)="openDialog()">Open dialog</button>
    
  **Parent component ts**
     
    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}
    
      openDialog() {
        this.dialog.open(DialogElementsExampleDialog);
      }
    
    
   **Parent component html**
    
    <h1 mat-dialog-title>Dialog with elements</h1>
    <div mat-dialog-content>This dialog showcases the title, close, content and actions elements.</div>
    <div mat-dialog-actions>
      <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
    </div>
    
  Your Modal will work so check in [Stackblitz Example][1]


  [1]: https://stackblitz.com/angular/rxblobloaqr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-elements-example.ts
```